# SQL query grammatical exception on converting recursive query to JPQL

Tags: sql, jpql

This is a JPQl query created from the below mentioned SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM NursingSectionHead head where head.secCode IN (" + 
            "WITH NUR_SECTIONS_SEC_CODE (secCode) " + 
            "AS (SELECT secCode " + 
            "FROM NursingSection " + 
            "WHERE secCode = (SELECT loc.nursingSecCode FROM LocationMast loc WHERE loc.id.locCode = :locCode) " + 
            "UNION ALL " + 
            "SELECT C1.secCode " + 
            "FROM NursingSection C1 " + 
            "INNER JOIN NUR_SECTIONS_SEC_CODE C2 ON C1.prevSec = C2.secCode)" + 
            "SELECT * FROM NUR_SECTIONS_SEC_CODE)
```

This is the SQL query:

```
select * from IR_TB_NUR_SEC_HEAD head where HEAD.SEC_CODE IN (
WITH NUR_SECTIONS_SEC_CODE (SEC_CODE)
AS (
     SELECT SEC_CODE
    FROM IR_TB_NUR_SECTIONS
    WHERE SEC_CODE = (select LOC.NURSING_SEC_CODE from mst_tb_location_mast loc where LOC.LOC_CODE = 20023)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C1.SEC_CODE
    FROM IR_TB_NUR_SECTIONS C1
    INNER JOIN NUR_SECTIONS_SEC_CODE C2 ON C1.PREV_SEC = C2.SEC_CODE
    )
SELECT *
FROM NUR_SECTIONS_SEC_CODE)
```

When executing it returns the below error:

> "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
>   could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet"

What can I do about the above exception, please?

Answer (score 0):

The "WITH" clause you are using  is known as Common Table Expression (CTE) .I am pretty sure CTE is not supported by JPQL because if it is supported , no one will specially develop a [library](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/core/manual/en_US/15_cte.adoc#implementation-notes) for supporting CTE query but only for Hibernate.

But you can switch to do use native SQL which should always work provided that your query can really be executed successfully against the database that you are using.